# How do you... open an existing unit test project in LDRA TBrun?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stm32, tbrun, ldra

I have an existing project that has quite a lot of LDRA TBrun .tcf files with test cases for the project. I'm trying to get up and running on these existing test cases and rerun the tests.

How... do I do this? There doesn't seem to be a way to just, open up a TCF, hit run, and it "just works". I have to I guess create a new sequence and import the test cases from the TCF instead. But only after I first open a set of code files from that TCF, or manually create that set of files, and THEN only after LDRA finishes analyzing the code for ten minutes. And if any of that fails for some reason, start over from scratch with a slightly different workflow to see if it goes any better. And in some cases, delete the local project folder because the local project cache gets corrupted.

Am I missing something? How do I just open an existing set of test cases and run them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> There doesn't seem to be a way to just, open up a TCF, hit run, and it "just works".

Err... TBrun provides EXACTLY this feature

[image: TBrun provides EXACTLY this feature]

For more information, the "Getting Started" guide has all the necessary instructions...
[image: the "Getting Started" guide]

But if you need further help, contact LDRA Support at support@ldra.com and they can work you through the steps.

See profile for affiliation!

Comment: "File/Set from TCF..." is not the same as "Open...". If you're a new user or intermittent user it's not clear where to start, without going through lots of documentation and going through the documentation again and then resorting to asking others, such as LDRA Support or coworkers. Google-able answers would go a long way to answering these simple questions. Thus this Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I could have just answered RTFM...  but the benefit of having a commercial product is you get support from the people who know best, not some other random person on SO.  Respectfully, this is the best answer you are likely to get here on SO.